# RIA Framework: Which is best free opensource RIA Framework for Java Developers?

Tags: apache-flex, extjs, ria, vaadin

Can you please give me suggestion as I wanted to find out which is the preferred Java RIA framework for most developers and why? I'm a newbie in RIA so need advise from you guys. I heard that FLEX Adobe is dead? Right now I'm thinking between Vaadin or Sencha but I still have not much idea. I would really appreciate any advise. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Flex is not dead yet . your choices are not that great . Depends on what you want JSF with Rich or Prime faces is popular. For fat clients like flex GWT is a better option.

Comment: Hi @Shahzeb thank you for your reply. I was really disturb to hear rumors that Flex is dead because actually I thought its a good choice for me. Can you please tell me why Vaadin or Sencha is not great option? Yes I agree with you that GWT is better option. Tnxs

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm currently using ExtJS (Sencha) and Vaadin in two different projects.

I personally enjoy Vaadin more than ExtJS, because

- my Java skills are much stronger than my JS skills
- I'm able to develop cool UI's very fast
- the community (ie. including the people who work for Vaadin) support is *awesome* and very friendly (unlike in the ExtJS forum where quite a many of the community and even staff members can be slightly arrogant)
- the documentation is way better
- you get the latest version immediately after release, whether or not you have a paid subscription
- the application logic is on the server side
- there are lots of addons, most of them free.

ExtJS is more widely used and doesn't require you to use a specific language / technology on the server side. I use it because the application's backend is written in PHP.

Comment: Hi miq, thanks for sharing your experience and helping me decide! I agree with you.

Comment: What is the story of vaadin for mobile devices -is the UI developed responsive? Will it work seamlessly across any of the devices (iPad, Mobile, PC etc.)

Answer (score 4):

My choice is [Vaadin](https://vaadin.com/home). Why? Many "ready-to-use" components available, easy to redesign UI according to my needs, quick UI, easy coding (like in Swing) and the biggest benefit, I don't have to deal with JavaScript!

I think you are not going to build classical web page but application, so both are good. You might maybe compare how these frameworks are documented and supported.

Also, you could build PoC with both framewors, so you are able to make your choice properly

Comment: Hi Ondrej, thanks for sharing your experience and helping me decide! I agree with you.